# Facebook SDK for android doesn't generate R class

Tags: android, facebook, resources, code-generation, android-resources

I've downloaded the Facebook SDK for android, and I've downloaded the files to my workspace and imported as an existing android project the "facebook" folder inside the sdk folder.
But somehow the R class refuse to generate and this library doesn't have xml resources at all! Just pictures!
I'm using the latest ADT and SDK tools, I'm trying to make it work for something like a hour and it's driving me crazy. I tried to clean the project and every other solution I found on the internet.

Please help me!

Comment: have you done step 4 : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sample - that's the project you want to build, not the facebook thing

Comment: The facebook sdk conatins three folders, "example", "tests" and "facebook". The "facebook" folders is what I need to build ("Create project from existing source and specifying the facebook directory from your git repository (~/facebook-android-sdk/facebook)."), and that's what I chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.
I left the facebook and started working on my app, and when I tried to add a string resource the R class didn't regenerate, so I downgraded to SDK Tools rev. 18 and it magically started working again, including the facebook SDK.

Google must do something about her ADT and SDK, it has so many bugs that can drive you crazy, when you think that they published a new SDK/ADT that gonna solve all the bugs, you are disappointed to find that it added more bugs.
This bug wasted me almost a day of work, and that's not cool.

Thanks